# Toggle class not working for slide page

Tags: javascript, function, toggle

I'm making a new page slide up effect and I want to use a little JS. Does anyone know why the toggle function isn't working?

Here's a fiddle `fiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/wtbdxx2b/1/

Comment: did you include jquery?

Comment: Yep, missing jquery mostlikely.  In case you don't know, include the library in jsfiddle and put something like this at the top of your html: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
</script>`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know much about JS or Jquery, I did some research and now I think I get it. It work's now btw: https://jsfiddle.net/wtbdxx2b/6/